# Python profiling - recognize built-in hash function usages

Tags: python, profiling, cprofile

I'm using `cProfile` library to do profiling on my `python` code.

Currently, the most used function that I see in the process is:

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
4845420/1329718    2.528    0.000    3.739    0.000 {built-in method builtins.hash}
```

I guess it's a set/dict-related/compare operation of one of my classes. I want to find which class is the one that its `hash` method takes the most time. Any ideas on how can I find which compare is this?

Comment: why would `hash` be involved in a comparison operation? That is likely something like involving a `dict` or a `set`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga you right, my mistake, I'll edit